# Why was Ergotamine (trade name: Cafergot) discontinued in Canada and UK?

Tags: medications, migraine

My mom in HK was prescribed Ergotamine, but I'm unnerved discontinuation in Canada and UK! Something wrong with it?

[**Asked**
13 Oct 2012 by lucyglitters](https://www.drugs.com/answers/cafergot-discontinued-604344.html)

> i live in the uk and i've been taking it for more than 30 years to control my 3-4 migraines a week - just went to get a prescription renewed and i'm told it's no longer available in the uk - at this point in time, all i can see is losing my job and then losing my house and ending up on the streets! does anybody have any information? have tried all other migraine meds and prophylactics but nothing else works for me .

[GeoffG 23 Jun 2014](https://www.drugs.com/answers/cafergot-discontinued-604344.html)

> Cafergot was recently discontinued in Canada. None of the expensive designer drugs was as effective. I found a suggestion online that a _compounding pharmacy_ could compound it. My doctor found one, Smith's Pharmacy in Toronto, and I now have Cafergot once again! I had them compound it in a half strength dosage, 0.5 mg ergotamine tartrate and 50 mg caffeine citrate, which usually is enough for me (half a tablet). Works like a charm!

Comment: This is interesting as the British National Formulary [only states](https://bnf.nice.org.uk/drug/ergotamine-tartrate.html) that *"Ergotamine tartrate is less suitable for prescribing"* and *"Not licensed for the management of cluster headache"*.

Comment: @ChrisRogers i up-voted you! i didn't even see that!!! good eye!

Comment: @ChrisRogers Be aware that that link isn't viewable outside the UK.

Comment: That's interesting @CareyGregory - Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Where did you find it was discontinued? https://www.healthcentral.com/article/fda-orders-20-unapproved-ergotamine-medications-discontinued says it's OK (but that's FDA), https://www.rexall.ca/articles/view/1047/Cafergot#availableform_title says it isn't, https://www.canadianpharmacyking.com/Landing.aspx?drug=Cafergot+Tablets sells it, and nothing really turns up on a search for 'Ergotamine - caffeine canada'.